# Babylon.js model animation is clipped when I move around it

Tags: animation, 3d, render, babylonjs

I have a babylon.js 3D environment, where I load a gtb model with skeletal animation. The model and animation look fine in Babylon Sandbox. However, when I load it within my 3D environment, the moving animation part partially disappears, as I move about (without getting too close).

Can a babylon.js/3d environment/webGL pros have tips on possible causes for this?